# Return all users with role id in a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 tables: User, Roles, and UserRoles and I have a list of roles ids `{ 2, 3, 4 }`.  I want to return all users that have an id with either 2, 3 or 4.

Models:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Roles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserRoles
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
    public virtual Roles Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And the code I have:

```
int[] RoleIds = { 2, 3, 4 };
return await _dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserRoles.Any(x=> RoleIds.Contains(x.RoleId)));
```

I don't know why but my result contains records with roleId == 1.

### update

I know why.. My code is correct. There is something wrong in the Mapper class. 
I used something like .FirstOrDefault().RoleId. so it only returns the first data, and a user may have multiple roles! Thank you guys

Comment: aand, what is the result of this?

Comment: Ya, you are right, the question doesn't make much sense. But probably you are looking to do a join on two/three tables, which is available in Linq.

Comment: my result contains records with roleId == 1 ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try going backwards and see if that helps...

```
return await _dbContext.UserRoles
     .Where(r => RoleIds.Contains(r.RoleId))
     .Select(r => r.Users)
```

Comment: Note that `Roles` doesn't have a navigational property to `User` nor to `UserRoles`, so you have to add that to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're trying to get the User from the UserRole relationship table.

Here's how to do it in query expression syntax:

```
int[] RoleIds = { 2, 3, 4 }; 

var users = from ur in _dbContext.UserRoles
            where RoleIds.Contains(ur.RoleId)
            select ur.Users;
```

Or if you don't want or have navigational properties:

```
int[] RoleIds = { 2, 3, 4 }; 

var users = from ur in _dbContext.UserRoles
            where RoleIds.Contains(ur.RoleId)
            join user in _dbContext.Users
            on ur.UserId equals user.Id
            select user;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to add navigational properties to `User` nor to `Roles`, you can do this easily using LINQ query syntax:

```
var usersQuery = from role in _dbContext.Roles
                 join userRole in _dbContext.UserRoles 
                     on role.Id equals userRole.RoleId
                 join user in _dbContext.Users
                     on userRole.UserId equals user.Id;
                 where roleIds.Contains(role.Id)
                 select user;

var users = usersQuery.ToList();
```